# Convert Facebook feed into some data source

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I get Facebook feed by Graph  API and need some tool/something to represent each item like a Wall Post.

My question are there any free/open source dll which I can use it to transform result into some datasource to use under WPF?

Thank you!

```
string AccessToken = string.Concat(appID, "|", secretKey);
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
dynamic feed = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get(profileID + "/feed");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the result you can use [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/), and for working with Facebook graph API I would recommend [Facebook SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/)